# Abelianess of the category of projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, projective-module

Let $A$ be an algebra, over $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}$, say. Under what conditions on $A$ will its category of projective left $A$-modules be abelian?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I would imagine the answer is "only in the trivial case when every module is projective, i.e. $A$ is semisimple", but proving it seems a bit tricky.